# How to connect remote Linux Machine via SSH

Tags: ssh, remote-management

I want to connect remote my linux machine via SSH. What should I do for this?

Comment: Reading the man page is always a good first step when learning a new tool.  Start with `man ssh`.  Another issue to consider is whether the system you want to access is directly on the internet, or behind a firewall.  You may need to learn how to use Google to find the technical manual for your particular model of router or firewall, and how to configure it to allow TCP passthrough of port 22, for example.

Answer (score 3):

In order to connect via ssh from one machine to another you must have a `ssh server daemon` on the "server" host, a `ssh client` on the "client" host, you must have valid credentials on the "server" and your firewall must be setup to allow connections on the server machine, if using any. Many distributions have already setup these packages by default, such as Ubuntu and Fedora. Hopefully these are all the necessary steps for these two major distributions on its current versions (Ubuntu 19.04 and Fedora 30). Let me know if something is missing.

### Server Machine

1. Install a SSH Server, if it is not already installed (e.g.: openssh-server).

**Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

**Fedora**

```
sudo dnf install openssh-server
```

2. Enable the SSH Server Daemon, if it is not already enabled.

**Ubuntu**

```
sudo systemctl enable ssh
sudo systemctl start ssh
```

**Fedora**

```
sudo systemctl enable sshd
sudo systemctl start sshd
```

3. Enable the service or open the port on the firewall, if it is not already open.

**Ubuntu**

```
sudo ufw allow ssh

... or ...

sudo ufw allow 22
```

**Fedora**

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=<ZONE> --add-service=ssh --permanent

... or ...

sudo firewall-cmd --zone=<ZONE> --add-port=22/tcp --permanent
```

### Client Machine

1. Install a SSH Client, if it is not already installed (e.g.: openssh-client).

**Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt install openssh-client
```

**Fedora**

```
sudo dnf install openssh-client
```

2. Connect to the server machine

```
ssh <SERVER_ADDRESS>

... or ...

ssh <USER>@<SERVER_ADDRESS>
```

3. Optionally, make your access easier to your server machine by configuring your `~/.ssh/config` file.

```
vi ~/.ssh/config
```

... and then add to it something like...

```
Host <NAME>
  Hostname <SERVER_ADDRESS>
  Port 22
  User <USER>
```

... and then you are able to connect to the server just by typing...

```
ssh <NAME>
```